# Windows 2012 Server, ONLY command prompt access to administrator

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, cmd.exe, windows-server-2012

Is there anyway I can create a Administrator in Windows server and give access ONLY to command prompt. Due to some reasons, We want to give access to ONLY to command prompt for admin users in Windows server. How can we achieve this ?

We are able to achieve this objective using SSH to Windows Server, We have installed freesshd in Windows server and this way, When administrator logs into server, he has access to command prompt and not the GUI. But When doing this way, the prompt or the screen is not getting refreshed properly.  That's why i am looking for an alternate method.

BTW:We are using Linux Desktop, So the solution should work from linux desktop.

Comment: If they are Administrators, then they can undo anything you do.  If you want to use SSH, and the existing SSH server/client isn't working as expected, why not try another SSH server and client?

Comment: I want to give this cmd prompt to junior system admin, with set of commands to be executed. This way, I can avoid accidental mistakes done by Junior system admins. In anyway, We can not avoid the deliberate